# Browser starts downloading and opening hundreds of tabs when I try to run my php scripts

Tags: php

I tried to include my first php script in one of my html docs.  The code is below.

```
<?php
$dir="pictures";
$listOfPictures = scandir($dir);

for($i=2; $i<count($listOfPictures); $i++){
    echo "<img src=\"pictures/" . $listOfPictures[$i] .
    "\" alt=\"picture\" height=\"250px\" width=\"150px\"" .
    "onclick=\"showImage(this.src, 'pictures/" .
    $listOfPictures[$i] . "');\"/>\n";
}
?>
```

When I first tried to open the .html.php file it started opening hundreds of tabs and storing the html doc hundreds of times in my /tmp directory.  I thought it was my code at first so I reduced the loop to only 10 times (the size of that array is about 500) thinking that was the problem.  It just did it again.  So then I created a basic php script like below.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php
    echo 'Hello world';
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And it still did it.  Any suggestions? Any details I need to add? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I can run php programs fine from the command line.  The above script outputs exactly what I expect.  I am running apache on arch linux.

Comment: This is probably related to your hoster...

Comment: This is at my house on my PC.  Everything is being run locally.

Comment: Sounds like maybe your server isn't executing your php correct, and is triggering some sort of downloading? Did you set the server up yourself or are you using some sort of hosting?

Comment: What setup did you do? Are you running windows or mac?

Comment: I'm running apache on arch linux.  Standard install.  I do not recall editing any of the apache config.

Comment: How are you opening your file in the browser?

Comment: I would see what the webbrowser is actually getting from the server. Debug mode in the browser? Also,  I would look at the apache / php error logs to see if there are any clues there as to what is happening. It sounds odd. Would be interesting to know what the cause is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what's happening is this:

When you double click the file your browser tries to open it, not knowing how to process PHP extension it tries to open it as-if it were a downloaded file. I assume the default software to open a PHP is your browser. This happens repeatedly in a loop.

To get Apache to open it, open a tab in your web browser normally and go to `http://localhost/index.php`

(I assume here that your file is called `index.php` and is in whatever is set for your Apache's DocumentRoot).

Comment: I'll try this tonight after work and let you know how it goes.  Is there a way to configure my browser to read php files? I like to tweak my html files in a separate directory and then move them to apache when I know they are stable.

Comment: You don't want to configure it, your web browser is the client/consumer of the output of the PHP code. PHP files are just text, the web server (Apache) uses the extension .php as well as the opening/close tags to launch the PHP preprocessor, as necessary. The code is run and the end result (HTML) is sent back to your browser that knows how to render it.

Comment: This is what was wrong.  I was trying to run it from browser and not the server.

Comment: Awesome, glad we narrowed down the issue and it works now :)